# Error in CSV Writing - Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm running this code [self explanatory] :

```
import csv

word_list = ["Hello1;;;;World1", "Hello2;;;;World2"]

with open('words.csv', 'w') as new_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(new_file, delimiter=',')

    for line in word_list:
        csv_writer.writerow(line.split(';;;;')[0] + "\t" + line.split(';;;;')[1])
```

I'm expecting the csv to be :

```
Hello1, ,World1
Hello2, ,World2
```

I'm getting :

```
H,e,l,l,o,1,    ,W,o,r,l,d,1
H,e,l,l,o,2,    ,W,o,r,l,d,2
```

What's the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`writerow`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow) takes an iterable. In your code this is the string build by

```
line.split(';;;;')[0] + "\t" + line.split(';;;;')[1]
```

This string is iterated, every item in it (= every character) is put into a cell.

Try

```
csv_writer.writerow([line.split(';;;;')[0], "\t", line.split(';;;;')[1]])
```

Comment: Great. Works. Thanks!